# Flex wrap not working with fixed width container

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flex-box container with two child containers where the right should fold under the left at smaller screens. However, this only seems to work when the parent container width is 100% and not when it's set to a fixed width. It needs a fixed width based on a design, and I've tried wrapping the fixed width container in a parent container with a 100% width, but this isn't effective.

How can I set the container with a fixed width so that the items wrap correctly at smaller screen sizes?

```css
.call-out-container {
  width: 1172px;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.call-out-box {
  color: #eee;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
 }

.call-out-box {
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
  color: #eee;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}

.call-out-box h1 {
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  color: #00477B;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 56px;
}

.call-out-box p {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="call-out-container">
  <div class="call-out-box">
    <div style="width: 540px; height: 365px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 80px; display: flex; border: 2px solid orange; justify-content: center;">
      <div style="width: 445px; height: 445px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); box-shadow: rgb(221, 221, 221) 0px 3px 11px 4px; position: relative; right: -30px; top: 20px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
        <p>CONTENT</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="call-out-list">
    <h1>10.5k</h1>
    <p>Line 1</p>
    <p>Line 2</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="call-out-container">
  <div class="call-out-list">
    <h1>10.5k</h1>
    <p>Line 1</p>
    <p>Line 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="call-out-box">
    <div style="width: 540px; height: 365px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 80px; display: flex; border: 2px solid orange; justify-content: center;">
      <div style="width: 445px; height: 445px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); box-shadow: rgb(221, 221, 221) 0px 3px 11px 4px; position: relative; right: -30px; top: 20px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
        <p>CONTENT</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JSFIDDLE LINK: [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/bow4dx5L/33/)**

Comment: There's not much use in flexbox if you're not going to flex :). I'd say the design needs to change.

Comment: Setting the `call-out-container` to `width: 100%` hides the right box under the left. Is there a flexbox property that I can use to not have it hidden?

Comment: It's doing that because you have set height in the inline styles of your first `call-out-box`. Set the height of the first `call-out-box` to be larger than that in your inline styles, or use `grid` as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: The question is unclear but does it help if you change it to `max-width: 1172px;`?

Comment: I updated my question with fixed code, but there's still unusual spacing between the rows when they're collapsed. I've added a jsfiddle link as its difficult to see whats happening on the code snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using flexbox, use grid, if those sizes are fixed.

```
.call-out-box{
/*other styles*/
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 540px 445px;
  grid-template-rows: 365px 445px;
}
```

the just remove the width and the height attributes in the in-line style.

Answer (score 0):

if sizes are fixed then use grid
also go [here jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ankitqode/g5bs186p/)

```css
.call-out-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.call-out-box {
  color: #eee;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 540px 445px;
  grid-template-rows: 365px 445px;
}

.call-out-list {
  color: #eee;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.call-out-list h1{
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  color: #00477B;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 56px;
}
.call-out-list p {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="call-out-container">
  <div class="call-out-box">
    <div style="width: 540px; height: 365px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 80px; display: flex; border: 2px solid orange; justify-content: center;">
      <div style="width: 445px; height: 445px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); box-shadow: rgb(221, 221, 221) 0px 3px 11px 4px; position: relative; right: -30px; top: 20px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
        <p>CONTENT</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="call-out-list">
    <h1>10.5k</h1>
    <p>Line 1</p>
    <p>Line 2</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="call-out-container">
  <div class="call-out-list">
    <h1>10.5k</h1>
    <p>Line 1</p>
    <p>Line 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="call-out-box">
    <div style="width: 540px; height: 365px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 80px; display: flex; border: 2px solid orange; justify-content: center;">
      <div style="width: 445px; height: 445px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); box-shadow: rgb(221, 221, 221) 0px 3px 11px 4px; position: relative; right: -30px; top: 20px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
        <p>CONTENT</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set  container to a fixed width or height if you want your flex wrap to work correctly when you decrease your viewport's width or height respectively.

For flex wrap to work correctly, your flex container's width or height should be
with respect to Viewport i.e in terms of **vw or vh.**

example:-

div{ width:80vw; height:70vh; display:flex; flex-direction:row; flex-wrap:wrap; }

Flex wrap exists to make your webpage more responsive.